# IOError when opening/writing file with "a" mode

Tags: python, io

I have the following Python code:

```
try:
    
    with open(self.file_name, "a") as log_file:
        log_file.write(...))
            
except IOError:
                
    print("I couldn't open the file")
```

The file is opened with **"a"** mode, so it appends the text at the end of the file AND, if the file doesn't exist, it creates one.

Now, `IOError` occurs when the file that we passed in as argument does not exist or it has a different name (or the file location path is incorrect).

So in what case Python will throw such an error when we use the "a" mode? When we run out of disk space? Are there any other cases?

Comment: As far as I now, 'a' expects that a file already exists, in other cases it raises IOError.

Comment: @CaptainTrunky well, no, "a" opens a file for appending. The file pointer is at the end of the file if the file exists. That is, the file is in the append mode. If the file does not exist, it creates a new file for writing

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych: there's no error at all, it is a theoretic question